# Datagridview nao armazena informaçoes na tabela

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

tenho um datagridview que é alimentado por uma pesquisa em um banco de dados para realizar uma venda
porem so consigo vender um produto de cada vez pois a tabela de vendas nao consegue receber 2 ou mais produtos simultaneamente
ja tentamos separar a tabela de vendas em 2: itens_venda e vendas, onde vendas armazena o codigo da venda, a forma de pagamento e a data, 
enquanto itens_venda armazena os produtos. Quando finalizo a venda só é feito o armazenamento na tabela de vendas(que é feito por uma procedure)
e na itens_venda nao acontece nada (o armazenamento aqui é realizado pelo table adapter e data table)
se voces puderem me ajudar ficaria muito grato

segue o código do botão de finalizar compra

```
private void btnFinCompra_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int codigo = Convert.ToInt16(TAVendas.insereVenda(DateTime.Now, pagamento));
            txtCodVenda.Text = codigo.ToString();
            try
            {
                for(int cont = 0; cont<=dgvVenda.Rows.Count - 2; cont++)
                {

                    DadosDataSet.tbitensvendaRow linha;
                    linha = (DadosDataSet.tbitensvendaRow)DTitens.NewRow();
                    linha.BeginEdit();
                    linha.codvenda = Convert.ToInt16(txtCodVenda.Text);
                    linha.codproduto = Convert.ToInt16(dgvVenda.Rows[cont].Cells["clmCodigo"].Value);
                    linha.nomecor = dgvVenda.Rows[cont].Cells["clmNomeCor"].Value.ToString();
                    linha.categoria = dgvVenda.Rows[cont].Cells["clmCategoria"].Value.ToString();
                    linha.subcategoria = dgvVenda.Rows[cont].Cells["clmSubCat"].Value.ToString();
                    linha.subcategoria2 = dgvVenda.Rows[cont].Cells["clmSubCat2"].Value.ToString();
                    linha.qtde = Convert.ToInt16(dgvVenda.Rows[cont].Cells["clmQtde"].Value);
                    linha.peso = Convert.ToDouble(dgvVenda.Rows[cont].Cells["clmPeso"].Value);
                    linha.marcatipo = dgvVenda.Rows[cont].Cells["clmMarcaTipo"].Value.ToString();
                    linha.precovenda = Convert.ToDouble(dgvVenda.Rows[cont].Cells["clmPreco"].Value);
                    linha.totalvenda = Convert.ToDouble(dgvVenda.Rows[cont].Cells["clmSubTotal"].Value);
                    linha.EndEdit();
                    DTitens.Rows.Add(linha);

                }
                TAitens.Update(DTitens);
                MessageBox.Show("Venda realizada com sucesso", "Vendas", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro ao finalizar compra\n" + ex.Message, "ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                TAVendas.excluirVenda(Convert.ToInt16(txtCodVenda.Text));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro ao finalizar compra\n" + ex.Message, "ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Qual é o erro apresentado no catch?

Comment: Ele não retorna erro pelo catch, o sistema ate faz o cadastro sem erros porem não armazena todos os dados no banco de dados, armazena somente os que estão atribuídos a stored procedure, os dados so datagridview eu não sei para onde vão.